# Connection timeout when connecting to server from android device

Tags: android

I am trying to connect from my android phone to my server. But I got time-out connection error. what can be the the cause?

note: i have changed my URL link to http://google.com and its working well, so please advice.

my code is

```
public static boolean bHasInternetAccess() 
    {  
        InputStream in=null;
        int response=-1;
        boolean bHasInternet=true;

        try
        {
            URL url=new URL("http://192.168.1.100/AWS.asmx/dtTickets?sTech_ID=-99");
            URLConnection conn= url.openConnection();
            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            {
                bHasInternet=false;
            }
            HttpURLConnection httpConn=(HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(15000); 
            httpConn.connect();
            response=httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if (response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                in=httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bHasInternet=false;
        }
        if (in==null) {
            bHasInternet=false;
        }
        return bHasInternet;         
    }
```

Comment: If google is working, then there is a problem with your network or server. Is the phone and server in the same network?

Comment: @Rvdk yes it is on the same network! any suggestions please ?

Comment: does the address work in Android browser?

Comment: @Axarydax no its not working

Comment: Then it also won't work in your application. First fix the connection problem, try to ping the computer from the phone, check the firewall, etc.

Comment: its firewall issue thanks for your responce